# google-visualization-table-page-numbers background color change

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to change what I would call the footer background color where the google-visualization-table-page-numbers go. I would like the background color to extend the entire width of the table. I am hoping someone can help me find the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the chart uses a gradient, use css `background` to change to a solid color

```
.google-visualization-table-div-page {
  background: magenta !important;
}
```

to keep the gradient and only change the color, use css `background-color`

```
.google-visualization-table-div-page {
  background-color: magenta !important;
}
```