# How to customize pagination footer of a Google Chart's table?

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

For my web application I developed a Statistic module and I used the Google Chart API to display my data in different way : ColumnChart, LineChart and Table.

I want to customize the Table GoogleChart Object. I know there are many  configuration options to add CSS but I saw nothing about the paging/footer part.

Is there a way to customize easily with something like :

```
var cssClassNames = {footerRow: 'bigAndBoldClass'};
```

or do I need to modify the 'google-visualization-table-div-page gradient' class applied by default by GoogleChart ?

Comment: to my knowledge, there aren't any options for styling paging section -- your guess is correct, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271819/5090771) for example snippet...